# connecting mule ESB to Apache web server

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

How to access the data packets routed to apache webserver in **Mule ESB** flow.
After I call the exposed webservice, the webservice sends two responses,

1. To mule server
2. Routes response XML as data packets to apache webserver.

Can someone help in how to proceed with second flow? Thanks.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you want to achieve from the description you've given. Can you show what config you have so far? This could help understand.

Comment: Thanks. How to obtain the Response XML contained as data packets in mule ESB by accessing the web server after the webservice been called?

Comment: It should be in the message payload.

Comment: Actually, the webservice sends two responses simultaneously. Mule application has one response in the payload and also I need to access the data sent to webserver which is another response as XML. So how to access it after the flow?

Comment: I don't understand how two HTTP responses can be simultaneously be returned. Can you share your current Mule config?

Comment: The webservice called via mule server sends response to apache web server which is configured internally as pcap file. And it just sends the status response as XML to mule which can be seen in the logger. Now, I need to access the data in mule??

Comment: I have attached the flow for your reference,    <flow name="muleFlow1"><http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://webservice address" doc:name="HTTP">
<set-property propertyName="Accept" value="application/xml"/>
</http:outbound-endpoint>
<logger message="Payload is    #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Mule Server Response"/>  
/*How to call the webserver to access data packets here?? */
</flow>

Comment: I guess you need to add another endpoint to fetch the data from the Apache web server. How do you usually get this PCAP data? I mean when you're not using Mule what command/tool/library do you use the retrieve the response?

Comment: Thanks. I used tcpdump to check data in linux terminal. which endpoint and also I need to get the data from server and combine it with what I receive in http endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Java library that understands PCAP and create your own Mule connector around it.

Reference:

- List of Java PCAP libraries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap#Wrapper_libraries_for_libpcap.2FWinPcap
- Mule connector development kit: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit

Comment: Thanks so much and will try as suggested.